# Decomposition of Projection Matrix into two Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

For $n$-vectors $a$ and $b$, the parallel component of $b$ onto $a$ can be calculated using projection matrix $M$ (assuming $||a|| = 1$), where $M$ equals cross product $a^T$ with $a$ itself, giving an $n\times n$ matrix $M$. The the parallel component is then found via Matrix vector multiplication: $Mb$. Since $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, this operation requires $n^2$ scalar multiplications. The question is: how can $M$ be decomposed into two matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$ such that $M1(M2b)$ = $Mb$, but the left hand calculation requires only $2n$ scalar multiplications instead of $n^2$.

This problem is out a "Coding the Matrix" textbook by Philip Klein (problem 8.3.17(#2)). Let me know if more description is required. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)^T$, and let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be the standard basis vectors.

Then, $Me_i=a_i\cdot a$. This is what we have to reproduce in two simpler steps.

So, simply map $e_i\mapsto a_ie_1$, say, for the first round (as $M_2$), then map $e_1\mapsto a$ and $e_i\mapsto 0$ for $i>1$ (as $M_1$).

Using matrices, this is just $M_1:=\Big(a|0|0\dots|0\Big)$ and $M_2:=\pmatrix{a^T\\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0}$.